# Selenium testing in a continuous integration pipeline

Tags: java, selenium, continuous-integration, devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Selenium test written in the Java language. I want to integrate these tests with the VSTS Continuous Integration Pipeline build.

When the build happens these Selenium tests should run.

What **tasks** should be added to the CI & configure the Selenium tests?

Please also provide URLs for details.

I searched on Google, but most of the Selenium tests used are written in .NET.

Comment: You can use maven as build tool to run your script in through pipe line

Answer (score 0):

If the test need to be run in interactive way, you need to setup a private build agent with Interactive mode. (e.g. [Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows)), then run test through this build agent.

There is the Maven task that can run java test. Check this article for more information: [Testing Java applications with VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/continuous-test-java)